# Can I delete multiple emails with the standard Android email app?

Tags: stock-email-app

I am using LG L3II E430 mobile with standard Android email app.

Can I delete multiple emails?

Answer (score 4):

*DISCLAIMER: This is based on the stock email app on a Samsung Galaxy S4.*

If you click on an email quickly, it opens that email.

If you long-press on an email, it selects that email without opening it. Then if you click another email, it also selects that. Now, you have two selected emails. You can then click the delete button to delete both emails.

Comment: FWIW: This is also true on my Nexus 5.

Comment: In the email list, tapping on the contact icon (or the colored letter representing the contact if it has no photo) also selects the e-mail.

Comment: @Chahk, is that the case on the non-Gmail email app as well?

Comment: @dotVezz Yes, i just verified it.

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the Contact icon or colored letter according to the Starting Letter of your mail Sender and select multiple mails that you want to delete it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to e-mail and select one by clicking on icon on left. Then click on checkbox icon on top banner to select all. You can then delete all or reselect those that you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings
Long tap on the concerned account. 
Under "sync settins" you will find "number of emails to load"
Long tap on this will give you a choice of 25, 50, 75, 100, 200 or all.
Select all 
Then when you want to delete all just go to your inbox, select edit, select all, tap delete above reading pane.
All your emails will be deleted
You will have to repeat this in recycle bin to permanently delete them all